# Iterable in apex batch start

Tags: apex, batch, asyncapexjob

Iterable had an upper limit of 10000 records in batch apex earlier, when used as return type for `start` method. However in docs, I cant seem to find it anymore. Is this limit removed or not relevant?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting question. Though other limits such as heap size will still apply.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you have perhaps a wayback machine link? I don't recall running in to such a limit even back in 2015... but that's been a while, I could be wrong.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150905170457/https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm shows basically the same thing as now. If it was documented, it wasn't on this page, or it's been more than 7 years since such a limit existed.

Comment: I'm sure I've tested iterables that surpassed more than 250,000 in a constrained use case; heap was the limiting factor